How does the server handle identical requests between multiple users without mixing up the responses?
I am not sure how to ask this, so I apologize if the above question is not very clear..
If user A and user B, from within their respective clients, both have a server request.. how does the server know which user requested what? If they both send the request at the exact millisecond, is there a chance the server may mix the response and send it to the wrong user? I'm assuming it's based on the headers?
I use node and SvelteKit, and am trying to deepen my layers of knowledge of how things work.
I'm sure this has been asked before, but I wasn't sure what to look for. I did find a few other related Stack Overflow posts while creating this post, but they didn't answer my question.
Any help with what to look for, or the technical terms for this, would also be helpful.

Did you look at CLS and specifically at cls-hooked built-in Node.js package?

It's based on a connection that is provided by the network protocols. Would recommend reading up on HTTP and TCP if the referenced question/answer is unclear. If you have any more specific questions about this process after doing so, feel free to ask a new and more targeted question.
